# vscode html settings not work on jsx

Tags: reactjs, format, visual-studio-code, jsx

"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-align" not work on jsx.

I would like format

```html
<RenderView key="1" 
  className="hah" 
  data="data"
/>
```

to

```html
<RenderView key="1" 
            className="hah" 
            data="data"
/>
```

How to did it?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code does not use the `html.*` formatting settings for jsx out of the box.

Please try using one of the alternate JavaScript formatted extensions on the marketplace, such as [react-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify), for this formatting style